# #1005 mysql error keys error

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I got this error

> ```
> #1005 - Can't create table 'tcf26469_sklepyinternetowe.ps_auctions_rutcom_bids' (errno: 150)
> ```

When i trying create table. I read many result on stackoverflow but I blind to see where is my error. I check type, create key , try CONSTRAINT  :(.
My Db create

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'ps_auctions_rutcom` (
        `id_auctions_rutcom` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        `id_product` INT( 11 ) unsigned NOT NULL,
        `id_customer` INT( 11 ) unsigned NOT NULL,
        `start_price` float unsigned NOT NULL,
        `min_price` float unsigned,
        `buy_now_price` float unsigned,
        `min_bit` float unsigned DEFAULT \'1\',
        `actual_bid_price` float unsigned,
        `max_bid_price` float unsigned,
        `max_bid_price_id_customer` INT( 11 ) unsigned NOT NULL,
        `start_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
        `finish_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
        `active` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT \'1\',
        `position` INT( 11 ) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',
        `finish` INT( 11 ) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id_auctions_rutcom`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Table what use FOREIGN KEY

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_auctions_rutcom_bids` (
    `id_auction_bid` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `id_auctions_rutcom` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `id_customer` INT( 11 ) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `bid_value` float unsigned,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_auction_bid`),
    Key `idauction` (`id_auctions_rutcom`),
    CONSTRAINT `idauction`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_auctions_rutcom`) REFERENCES auctions_rutcom  ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What i doing wrong? Where is error?

Comment: `'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '` the quotes are wrong for a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ps_auctions_rutcom`  instead of `auctions_rutcom`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_auctions_rutcom_bids` (
        `id_auction_bid` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        `id_auctions_rutcom` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `id_customer` INT( 11 ) unsigned NOT NULL,
        `bid_value` float unsigned,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id_auction_bid`),
        Key `idauction` (`id_auctions_rutcom`),
        CONSTRAINT `idauction`
        FOREIGN KEY (`id_auctions_rutcom`) REFERENCES ps_auctions_rutcom  ON DELETE CASCADE

    ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```